# Python List Not In / In Problems

Tags: python

I'm building a simple "20 question game" in Python but having some difficulty with the lists.

Here's my current code:

```
answer = []
animals = ['lion', 'tiger', 'human', 'zebra', 'horse', 'goat', 'bee', 'snake', 'narwhal']
legs = ['lion', 'tiger', 'zebra', 'horse', 'goat', 'bee']
stripes = ['tiger', 'zebra', 'bee', 'snake']
hooves = ['goat', 'horse']
horn = ['narwhal']
tail = ['lion', 'tiger', 'zebra', 'horse', 'goat']


legsq = input("Does it have more than 2 legs? ")
if(legsq.lower()=='yes'):
    for animal in legs:
        answer.append(animal)
else:
    for animal in animals:
        if animal not in legs:
            answer.append(animal)
print(answer)

stripesq = input("Does it have stripes? ")
if(stripesq.lower()=='yes'):
    for animal in answer:
        if animal not in stripes:
            answer.remove(animal)
else:
    for animal in answer:
        if animal in stripes:
            answer.remove(animal)

print(answer)
```

The problem is that when I run it, everything works fine, except after the second question some animals are in `answer[]` when they shouldn't be.

Here's an output that I got:

```
>>> 
Does it have more than 2 legs? yes
['lion', 'tiger', 'zebra', 'horse', 'goat', 'bee']
Does it have stripes? no
['lion', 'zebra', 'horse', 'goat']
```

Even though I answered no to the stripes question, zebra is still in there, even though zebra is in the stripes list, and it should be removed from answer if it's in the stripes list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you modify the list while you are iterating over it, it won't work as expected, so this doesn't work:

```
for animal in answer:  # Iteration over answer.
    if animal in stripes:
        answer.remove(animal)  # Modification of answer.
```

Here is how to fix it:

```
i = 0
while i < len(answer):
    if answer[i] in stripes:
        del answer[i]
    else:
        i += 1
```

This solution, as recommended by martineau, also works, because `answer[:]` makes a copy of `answer`:

```
for animal in answer[:]:
    if animal in stripes:
        answer.remove(animal)
```

(I agree with abamert on this.) Even though it works correctly here, I'd personally recommend against using `list.remove` in a loop in general, because `list.remove` looks for the matching value from the beginning of the list, and in some use cases this removes the wrong, unexpected element. If unsure, better stay away from this pattern (iteration + remove).

Please note that both the incorrect and correct solutions above are unnecessarily slow (O(n<sup>2</sup>) instead of O(n)) if `answer` is very long and there are too many items to remove. To speed it up in this case, create a new list:

```
answer = [animal for animal in answer if animal in stripes]
```

If `stripes` is also very long, you can make it even faster by converting `stripes` to a `set` first:

```
stripes_set = set(stripes)
answer = [animal for animal in answer if animal in stripes_set]
```

Comment: Or, instead of creating them as lists and converting them to sets at each step, just create sets in the first place. Or, even better, make `answer` a set as well, so the whole line is just `answer -= animal`.

Comment: `answer = [a for a in answer if a in stripes]`

Comment: While you're at it, add "goat" to "horn" list.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Your suggestion is already included in my answer. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Thank you! The answer = [animal for animal...] is a very nifty solution. I'll mark as correct when I'm allowed to. And thanks @LeeDanielCrocker, I'll add that.

Comment: BTW, creating a new list is probably faster in every case. Avoid using `del` if at all possible.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: And avoid using `remove` even more—it has to search for the value even though you already know where it is, and if there are duplicates it will often remove the _wrong_ value (there are hundreds of questions on SO about that…).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: It's definitely not faster in every case, for example if if `answer` and `stripes` are disjoint, then the solution with `del` is faster. So if we keep using lists, the speed depends on the input.

Comment: This isn't related to the question but about the line: `answer = [animal for animal in answer if animal in stripes]`. What does the first `animal` mean/do in `answer = [animal for animal...]`

Comment: @Kidd396: To answer your own question in the comment, try replacing the first `animal` with `'FOO'` or `animal * 2` and look how the output changes. If still unclear, ask it in a separate StackOverflow question.

Comment: @pts - Okay, so the first animal declares the variable name or behavior for the rest of the for/if. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Using the right data structures often makes things faster, as [pts's great answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27005134/908494). But it *also* often makes things *simpler*.

For example, if you have two sets, you can compute the intersection, union, set difference, etc. with a simple operator—concise, readable, and efficient. And, because sets, by their very nature, don't care about duplicate values, that whole "make sure it's there before we remove it" or "make sure it's not there before we add it" problem that you're having doesn't exist in the first place:

```
answer = set()
animals = {'lion', 'tiger', 'human', 'zebra', 'horse', 'goat', 'bee', 'snake', 'narwhal'}
legs = {'lion', 'tiger', 'zebra', 'horse', 'goat', 'bee'}
stripes = {'tiger', 'zebra', 'bee', 'snake'}
hooves = {'goat', 'horse'}
horn = {'narwhal'}
tail = {'lion', 'tiger', 'zebra', 'horse', 'goat'}

legsq = input("Does it have more than 2 legs? ")
if(legsq.lower()=='yes'):
    answer |= legs
else:
    answer -= legs
print(answer)
```

… and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It might make more sense to use the filter function or list comprehensions to do what you want.

```
answer = []
animals = ['lion', 'tiger', 'human', 'zebra', 'horse', 'goat', 'bee', 'snake', 'narwhal']
legs = ['lion', 'tiger', 'zebra', 'horse', 'goat', 'bee']
stripes = ['tiger', 'zebra', 'bee', 'snake']
hooves = ['goat', 'horse']
horn = ['narwhal']
tail = ['lion', 'tiger', 'zebra', 'horse', 'goat']


legsq = input("Does it have more than 2 legs? ")
if(legsq.lower()=='yes'):
    answer = [i for i in legs]
else:
    answer = [i for i in animals if i not in legs]
print(answer)
```

Let the language do the iterating for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not edit the list while iterating through the list.
Check if the animal still exists in the answer.
Then if the animal does not exist in the strips list, remove it.

```
if(stripesq.lower()=='yes'):
for animal in animals:
    if animal in answer:
        if animal not in stripes:
            answer.remove(animal)
else:
    for animal in stripes:
        answer.remove(animal)
```